Threshold moving with k-fold cross validation
I have an issue of class imbalance in my data (1:10 ratio), so I have implemented strategies, including Weighted Random Sampler, Weighted loss function, Threshold moving, Data augmentation (not always together but just observed how each strategy influences the test results).
I am currently working on binary classification problem with the cancer dataset. What I am curious about is if I have a K-fold cross validation workflow in the pipeline, how would I select the best threshold without hold-out test samples? What I have been reading online is that you should gather all metric-of-interest (for instance, F1-score) values based on each threshold and select the optimal threshold that results in the highest average F1-score over different folds outside of the cross validation loop. Could someone please share their knowledge on the above situation?
Another problem is that when I implemented the above, the optimal threshold was higher than 0.5, which was classifying all the positive samples to negative...as this leads to the high precision value. Obviously, this is not what I would like my classifier to do. Does that mean the threshold-moving technique is not the best with my data?
Thanks and could you also share any of your experience working with imbalance data?

Don't use accuracy, precision, recall, sensitivity, specificity, or the F1 score. Every criticism at the following threads applies equally to all of these, and indeed to all evaluation metrics that rely on hard classifications:
Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?
Is accuracy an improper scoring rule in a binary classification setting?
Classification probability threshold

Instead, use probabilistic classifications, and evaluate these using proper scoring rules.

With respect to class imbalance, also see Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?.

@StephanKolassa Thank you for sharing informative articles/posts. Does that mean AUROC and AP are somewhat more reliable metrics for the classification model evaluation than accuracy, precision, recall, F1-score etc..? - as they take different threshold values into account when calculating the values?
As my problem requires having fewer FN cases (Negative cases are expected to follow more invasive treatment schemes), I believe recall value is also important to measure..?

AUC is a semi-proper scoring rule and is somewhat better than measures that rely on "hard" classifications. By "AP", do you mean "average precision"? I do not know how this behaves, and would be careful about choosing an evaluation metric based on how nice it looks; your metric tells you and your model what prediction is a "good" one, and if this does not match what you actually want, you can be badly misled (Kolassa, 2020).

Per above, I would always prefer probabilistic models and evaluate them using proper scoring rules. Separate the decision aspect from the prediction aspect (see that thread on thresholds linked above).

I wouldn't always prefer probabilistic models (although I would always include them in the evaluation).  IF the metric of primary importance for the needs of the application involves the threshold (e.g. accuracy, F1 etc) THEN a direct discriminative classifier MAY give better results.  This is why the SVM often does well in such circumstances - backed up by plenty of theoretical work.  Here is one reason why https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312780/why-is-accuracy-not-the-best-measure-for-assessing-classification-models/538524#538524 .

It isn't a "one size fits all" thing, you need to understand the needs of the application and understand the tools and metrics well enough to make the right choices to meet the needs of the application (don't restrict yourself to one metric - use metrics that measure the aspects of performance relevant to the application).  The problem is that often practitioners apply "default" metric without really considering what is important to the client/user/application.
